# Ag-grid cell display wrong css format after edit

Tags: html, css, ag-grid

I'm learning ag-grid to display data into a grid. I've just started with a simple example to display simple data to cell using `cellRenderer`. You can exam on the code [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/qS6rhcukvJMc6Xmi):
`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script>
        var __basePath = '';
    </script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        span.cell1 {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            top: 50%;
            left: 10%;
            transform: translate(50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@20.2.0/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js">

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
    <script src="main.js">

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

`main.js`:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'gold',
        cellRenderer: params => {
            return '<span class="cell1">' + params.data.gold + '</span>';
        },
        editable: true,
    },
];

var gridOptions = {
    rowHeight: 60,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    agGrid
        .simpleHttpRequest({
            url:
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json',
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
        });
});
```

Please note the css I used:

```
span.cell1 {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                top: 50%;
                left: 10%;
                transform: translate(50%, -50%);
            }
```

I want to display the data in the middle of the cell (css: `top: 50%;`) so I tried with above css. But after edited, the cell didn't show as expected. Please help!
Render at start:
[image]
Render at editting:
[image]
Render after editted:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your CSS. Give `height` and `line-height` properties for `span.cell1` the same number which you provide to your `rowHeight`.

```
    span.cell1 {
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 60px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Have a look at the updated plunk: **https://next.plnkr.co/edit/4HHSANMjCpRkTdmm**